# Why i can't disable scroll in in-app browser when i follow link from Instagram?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, inappbrowser

I am having issues with vertical scrolling in in-app browsers.

[This is how I see my site when I try to open it from Instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv9iG.png)

[And this is how I see my site in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72mtG.png)

I use an iPhone SE.

This how I tried to fix it. But all I could do was raise the button from under the toolbar, but I did not solve the problem with the scrolling.

```js
function setHeight() {
    
    // Get window height without browser toolbar
    var windowsHeight = window.innerHeight;
    // I tried fix the problem by this way, but I think it's not smart
    var forinsta = windowsHeight - 70;

    // Determine where the user gets to the site
    var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    var isInstagram = (ua.indexOf('Instagram') > -1) ? true : false;

    if (isInstagram) {
        // If user gets to the site from Instagram, I set innerHeight -70px
        document.getElementById('wrapper').style.height = forinsta + 'px';
        document.body.style.height = forinsta + 'px';

    } else {
        // Else just set innerHeight
        document.getElementById('wrapper').style.height = windowsHeight + 'px';
        document.body.style.height = windowsHeight + 'px';
    }
}

setHeight();

window.onresize = function (event) {
    setHeight();
};
```

```css
html{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}


//Swiper
.swiper-container {
  position: absolute !important;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="swiper-container">
        <!-- I use swiper.js -->
        Slider Content
    </div>

</div>
```